# Console won't open when launching console application on startup VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, scheduled-tasks, console-application, startup

I have a console application that I can't seem to make launch properly on system startup.

I've debugged it by putting together a really simple console application that's simply just

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("This is a console application")
    Console.ReadLine()
    Environment.Exit(0)
End Sub
```

And even that won't work. The application is launching, I can see it in the task list. But the console interface isn't displaying, and that's the problem.

I've tried both using the Start Up folder and Windows Task Scheduler to get it to come up, neither seem to work.

Is there some registry setting somewhere I might change?

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: just for fun try putting the command to execute the application inside of a batch file (*.bat) and reference the bat file in the startup folder

Comment: Lots and lots of questions like this in the past 2 weeks.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: @Jeremy I've tried that, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @HansPassant The only antivirus I'm running is AVG. How does Avast effect windows task scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft, the task will only run interactively if the "Run only when user is logged in" radio button is selected.

"You can specify that a task should run even if the account under which the task is scheduled to run is not logged on when the task is triggered. To do this, select the radio button labeled Run whether user is logged on or not . If this radio button is selected, tasks will not run interactively. To make a task run interactively, select the Run only when user is logged on radio button."

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396